# How do I use the execute command against a named entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to do `/execute @e[type=Arrow,CustomName:"Flare"] ~ ~ ~` (very long command that I am doing) but it doesn't let me. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: If your sentence is too long, you need to put it in CommandBlock, which can execute infinite lenght of commands.

Comment: Actually Command blocks can't hold infinite code they can only hold 42,000 Characters more or less a thousand.

Answer (score 3):

CustomName is a NBT tag for entities, not a [target selector argument](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments). To select a entity with a custom name via target selector you need to use `@e[name=<CustomName>]`.

If you wish to use the NBT tag or multiple NBT tags to select a entity, you need to create a scoreboard objective in which you set the entities with the desired NBT tag using the Partial NBT Test parameter of `scoreboard`, then select the entities with the specified score:

Setup:

```
 /scoreboard objectives add selector dummy
```

Clock (20 tps):

```
 /scoreboard players set @e selector 0 //Reset the score
 /scoreboard players set @e selector 1 {<Desired NBT Tags>} //Set the score of all entities with the specified NBT Tags to 1
 /execute @e[score_selector_min=1] <x> <y> <z> <Command> //Selects all entities that have been marked by the last command block and executes a command on them
```

Comment: The last part is no longer true as of 1.13

Answer (score 0):

you are using **/execute @e[type=Arrow,CustomName:"Flare"] ~ ~ ~**
While you should use **/execute @e[type=Arrow,name:"Flare"] ~ ~ ~** Don't use CustomName just use name ('n' shouldn't be in Caps)